# Am I need to dispose all my stuff even I use the AssetManager?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, dispose

I am developing a platform game in libgdx. I use The AssetManager class to load all my assets to the game. So, My question is: Do I need to dispose my textures and atlases even when I am unloading them with the assets manager?

This is how I load them:

```
game.manager.load("img/background2.png",Texture.class);
game.manager.load("img/background2up.png",Texture.class);
game.manager.setLoader(TiledMap.class,new TmxMapLoader(new InternalFileHandleResolver()));
game.manager.load("maps/map15/map15.tmx",TiledMap.class);
```

This is how I unload them:

```
  game.manager.unload("maps/map15/map15.tmx");
  game.manager.unload("img/background2.png");
  game.manager.unload("img/background2up.png");
```

This is how I recieve, for example the backgrounds from the assats manager class:

```
background = game.manager.get("img/background2.png");
continBackground = game.manager.get("img/background2up.png");
```

Do I need to attach this to the dispose method?:
    background.dispose();
    continBackground.dispose();

Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to call dispose, calling unload is correct.

See here: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AssetManager

It says specificaly "**Assets managed via the AssetManager shouldn't be disposed manually, instead call AssetManager#unload()!**"